# mysql using the command line client- Image Loading

Tags: mysql

I am trying to load an image into mysql using the command line client and following is the the code that i have been using;

```
INSERT INTO AutomobileParts (Part_ID, Part_Name,Img_Path)
VALUES (
    "101AA",
    "BikePanel",
    load_file("F:/PYQT Projects/bikepanel.jpg")
) WHERE i=1;
```

can someone please help me out in understanding as in where i am going wrong on entering this piece of code.

Comment: what error are you shown when using above code?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE i=1' at line 1

Comment: What is i? Can you show your table structure?

Comment: although i have my table with 3 rows, the structure displays that i have 2 rows. I guess that should be the problem. although i save and run the forward engineer it still displays with only 2 rows.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL LOAD_FILE() reads the file and returns the file contents as a string.
That will probably not work with an image I guess.

Your field name "Img_Path" indicates that you only save the path in that field, not the image, and that the image itself is on your file system @ F:/PYQT Projects/bikepanel.jpg. This would be the normal way of saving images: The image file itself is in some folder on your server and you save the path to that folder in your table.

So if you want to show the image you would select the saved path from your MySQL table and read the file with your respective programming language (e.g. PHP or whatever you are using).

This might do the job unless there is an issue with variable "i" below:

```
INSERT INTO AutomobileParts (Part_ID, Part_Name,Img_Path)
VALUES (
    "101AA",
    "BikePanel",
    "F:/PYQT Projects/bikepanel.jpg"
) WHERE i=1;
```